# updating info on a custom setting from a response body, getting uncommitted work pending error

Tags: basics

I am getting this error because I am upserting a custom setting after each callout. What approach should I take to not have this issue?

The code below is a class with my @future callout method that I typically send my callouts from triggers through. This will be a scheduled job, however. As I couldn't get this to work there I made a copy that wasn't @future and started trying to work things out there, which is just below the first method. I am sure it will be apparent that I have been doing this for a month now so I have very little understanding of common practices.

```
public class SendGridAPI {
public static string keyid = system.label.keyid;
// This is the URL of your forwarding server
public static String endpointBase = 'https://api.sendgrid.com';
//Get the api key stored in encrpted text field
public static  String apikey = keyid;
public static String keybearer = 'BEARER ' + apikey;
// testing strings
public static string testbody = null; 
public static string testpoint = null;
public static integer scode = 0;

@future(callout=true)
public static void sendRequest(String json_payload, String endpoint, String httpMethod) {    
system.debug('keyid@@@@@ '+keyid);

  system.debug('jsonbody++++ ' + json_payload);

  //Instantiate an httpRequest and set the required attributes
  httpRequest req = new httpRequest();

      //if httpMethod is patch
    if(httpMethod == 'PATCH'){
        req.setMethod('POST');
        endpoint += '?_HttpMethod=PATCH';
    }else{
        req.setMethod(httpMethod);
    }

  req.setEndpoint(endpointBase + endpoint);
  system.debug(endpointBase + endpoint);

  // format headers 
  req.setHeader('Authorization', keyBearer);
  req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  system.debug(keybearer);

  // set json body from 
  req.setBody(json_payload);

  // prepart to send request
  httpresponse res = new httpresponse();
  Http h = new Http();

        // check if test is running
      if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
      res = h.send(req);
      system.debug(res);

      }         //do this if test running
          Else{
              testbody = '{"Status":"Created"}';
              testpoint = endpointBase +  endpoint;
              scode = 201;
  }

}

/*_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-*/      

public static string response{get; set;} 
public static string austinids = null;
public static string shayids = null;


public static string intRequest(String json_payload, String endpoint, String httpMethod) {    
system.debug('keyid@@@@@ '+keyid);

  system.debug('jsonbody++++ ' + json_payload);

  //Instantiate an httpRequest and set the required attributes
  httpRequest req = new httpRequest();

      //if httpMethod is patch
    if(httpMethod == 'PATCH'){
        req.setMethod('POST');
        endpoint += '?_HttpMethod=PATCH';
    }else{
        req.setMethod(httpMethod);
    }

  req.setEndpoint(endpointBase + endpoint);
  system.debug(endpointBase + endpoint);

  // format headers 
  req.setHeader('Authorization', keyBearer);
  req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  system.debug(keybearer);

  // set json body from 
  req.setBody(json_payload);

  // prepart to send request
  httpresponse res = new httpresponse();
  Http h = new Http();

        // check if test is running
      if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
      res = h.send(req);
      system.debug('response!!@@!!@@!!   '+res);

      if (res.getStatusCode() == 201) {
        // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
        response = res.getBody(); system.debug('response<><><><>  '+response);
        Map<String, object> results = (Map<String, object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        // Cast the values in the 'animals' key as a list
        object idstring = results.get('sender_id');
        integer senderid = integer.valueOf(idstring);
        System.debug('sender returned<><><> '+senderid);
        object campaignstring = results.get('id');
        integer campaignid = integer.valueOf(campaignstring);
        System.debug('CAMPAIGNid returned<><><> '+campaignid);
        if (senderid == 161861){
            austinids += senderid; system.debug('austinids'+austinids);
          }
        if (senderid == 161860){
            shayids += senderid; system.debug('shayids'+shayids);

          }
        }


      }         //do this if test running
      Else{
        testbody = '{"Status":"Created"}';
        testpoint = endpointBase +  endpoint;
        scode = 201;
  }

    sendgridsettings__c sgsshay = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance('shay');
    sendgridsettings__c sgsaustin = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance('austin');

    sgsshay.campaign_ids__c = shayids;
    //upsert sgsshay;
    sgsaustin.campaign_ids__c = austinids;
    //upsert sgsaustin;
  return response;
 }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that your upsert should be part of a different method that can be called or executed after your REST callout completes but should not be part of the Callout itself.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means you cannot make a callout after DML operation within same transaction. If you are calling this method more then once from same transaction you will get this error. 
Try to bulkify your process where you make callout before  DML operation.
Or you can split each call in different transaction or use batch class with batch size 1.